# Best approach to find the last n files created in a folder in linux, based on a timstamp comparision

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I need a list of files which were created after a certain period of time.

I had used the following piece of code to achieve the same :

```
for p, ds, fs in os.walk(idirpath):
    for fn in fs:
        filepath = os.path.join(p, fn)
        if datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filepath)) >= datetime.datetime.strptime(lasfilecredt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):
           filelist.append((filepath, os.path.getmtime(filepath)))
```

Where :
idirpath has the path where the files to be selected are present.

lasfilecredt has the timestamp value used for identifying the files required.

filelist is used to store the files identified along with their creation time.

Is there a better way to achieve this?. I had tried subprocess.popen in the past but wanted to go with this option for ease of maintenance of my code in the future.

Are there any specific scenarios when the above piece of code might not correctly identify the required files.

The above piece of code is being used to make sure that previously processed files are not being selected again in the next run (the '>=' symbol in the IF condition is to make sure we do not over-do the selection of files, else there is no reason not to have '>').

This code when deployed in production seems to fail randomly, atleast twice in three months.

Need some suggestions/help to identify the scenarios when this could possibly fail.

Comment: Why you don't use the OS functionality `ls -t /your/path/here | head -n` with python to get the files you need ?

Comment: @zochamx because it's stupid to parse ls output and issue complex shell commands when python can do it natively

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre stupid based on performance, lines of code, or sth else ? I suggested the shell command based on the fact that easily you can get a string with exactly what you want.

Comment: stupid based on complexity: several technologies mixed together when you can use only one, also "don't parse the output of ls" is a remark that pops up regularly here, and there's the `subprocess` interface that is error-prone (with spaces, quotes, ...)